# msxml3.dll error '800c0005' Classic ASP Error

Tags: asp-classic, msxml3

I am getting following error in Classic ASP

msxml3.dll error '800c0005'

System error: -2146697211.

This can be server issue with MSXML ? i am on windows 2003 server

Comment: Have you checked what versions of MSXML are inatalled on the Server?

Comment: Yes it has XML3.0, 4.0, 6.0 installed